# hide/show div using radiobuttons in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`<%= f.radio_button :newCustomer, "Male",:value=>'NewCustomer',:checked=>true%>`

```
 `<%= f.radio_button :customer, "Female",:value=>'Customer'%>`
```

`<div id="first"></div>`
`<div id="second"></div>`

I am new in rails.I have two radiobuttons and two div.When i click `NewCustomer` i want to hide `first` div and when i click on the `Customer` show the hidden div.I want to do this in only Ruby code.Is there any radiobutton click event like in .net

Comment: You either have to do this in `javascript` `hide` and `show` or make an ajax request on click of the radio button which hits the action that returns js which in-turn hides or shows the divs.(Use the second option only if you need it to hit the server)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by `Javascript` / `JQuery` / `Ajax` in rails:

Example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="female" />
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="male" />
<hr />
<div id="female" class="none">Div for Male</div>
<div id="male" class="none">Div for Female</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.none {display:none;}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(':radio').change(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
});
```

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgXSR/366/)

Answer (score 1):

**Pipeline**

To further `Gagan`'s answer, you'll want to include your Javascript in the `asset_pipeline`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", ".radio", function(){
   // gagan's code here
});
```

--

**Turbolinks**

Something to note is the importance of the [javascript "delegation"](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) - when you use Rails applications with Turbolinks.

Because of the way in which Turbolinks will just update the `<body>` tag of your page, many JS event bindings will actually become invalid, preventing your application from loading correctly.

To fix this, you need to be able to either delegate your DOM events from a "container" element (typically `document`), or by encapsulating your code in [Turbolinks events](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) like so:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var change = function() {
   $(".radio").on("change", function(){
       //Stuff here
   });
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", change);
```